How to create a library of reusable modules in NestJS for internal use as npm dependencies?
I would like to create a library of reusable modules for my company in NestJS that can be imported as npm dependencies into various projects. The goal is to avoid rewriting common modules like Authentication, Cache, Logger, etc. for every new project.
In the past, I've used Lerna to create NPM packages with a structure like @[company-name]/[module-name], and I'd like to replicate something similar using the NestJS library structure.
Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this in NestJS? Specifically:

How do I structure my code to create these modules as libraries?
How do I publish them as npm packages to be easily reusable across different projects?

To be more precise, I would like to accomplish something like it's happening in Angular where all the @angular/[module] share also the same version.

I'm not using NestJS but nowadays I use pnpm :workspace protocol which is great for monorepo and then I use Lerna-Lite (which I maintain) to version & publish releases (Lerna-Lite is same original code as Lerna except that it doesn't require Nx and is also entirely modular, install only what you use).

Fact is that I would love to use the library structure provided from NestJS using nest generate lib [lib-name]
